# How to get User object from id discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a bot that sends dm pings to a user whos Id is given as a parameter in a command.
This is the command:`.spam ID #_OF_PINGS`
I run into the following error:

```py
Ignoring exception in command spam:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "bot.py", line 16, in spam
     await ctx.send(f'Started pinging {user.name} {num} times.')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
     discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Here is my code:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
token = 'MyBotTokenHere'
prefix = '.'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
client.remove_command("help")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')


@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, id1: int, num: int):
    user = client.get_user(id1)
    await ctx.send(f'Started pinging {user.name} {num} times.')
    for i in range(num):
        await user.send(f'<@{str(id1)}>')
    await ctx.send(f'Finished {num} pings for {user.name}')


client.run(token)
```

It was working fine yesterday, but today, it broke down for some reason.
How do I fix it?
P.S. I hosted it on Heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a converter for this:

```
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, user: discord.User, num: int):
    await ctx.send(f'Started pinging {user.name} {num} times.')
    for i in range(num):
        await user.send(f'<@{str(id1)}>')
    await ctx.send(f'Finished {num} pings for {user.name}')
```

This way, Discord will automatically try to get the `discord.User` instance that corresponds to the `id` that you pass as an argument, and you can also `@mention` someone if you want to & it'll still work.

Also, starting from Discord 1.5.0, you now need to pass in `intents` when initializing a bot, which you clearly aren't doing yet. Update your Discord, and use the following to initialize your bot:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)
```

More info on the how's and why's of `intents` in the relevant [API documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents). You'll also want to enable `members` on your bot's Privileged Intents page, which is explained in the linked API docs as well.

Comment: i don't want to ping them that's the thing. also I completely forgot the intents.

Comment: Still works without pinging, I just said that it'll _also_ work if you want to do it anyways

Comment: still an error, in line     await ctx.send(f'Started pinging {user.name} {num} times.')

Comment: And you've fixed all the intents & updated the dpy version?

Comment: yes, requirements state that it needs discord.py, therefore making it the newest version, and I fixed intents

Comment: In that case, can you try using `fetch_user` instead of `get_user`

Comment: I realized that i had get_user(discord.User)